# Ace editor: how to have multiple tokens

Tags: ace-editor

I'm trying to create a mode using this two rules:

```
{
    token: 'title',
    regex: /#.*/
},

{
    token: 'name',
    regex: /@\w+/
}
```

Hovewer, the name rule will not have any effect in this example:

```
# Title with @name
```

Is there a way to make both rules work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first rule consumes the whole line and doesn't allow the second one to apply. For it to work, you need to create a nested state after the `#`

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
"use strict";

var oop = require("../lib/oop");
var TextHighlightRules = require("./text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;

var HighlightRules = function() {
    this.$rules = {
        start : [ {
            token: 'comment',
            regex: /#(?=.)/,
            next: [{
                token: 'empty',
                regex: /$|^/,
                next: "start"
            },{
                token: 'keyword',
                regex: /@\w+/
            },{
                defaultToken : "comment"
            }]
        }]
    };

    this.normalizeRules();
};

oop.inherits(HighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);

exports.HighlightRules = HighlightRules;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. After two days without any progress, substituting `'$'` with `'$|^'` made the trick :)